# Adding values to array without overwriting

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

Using a simple Java array called `int score[]`, I wish to store in the array
the int 1 or 0.

The `int`s are supplied from a simple math question and an if statement, that allows a 1 to be added to the array if a correct answer is given, or a 0 if the answer is incorrect.

There are only 5 math questions to try, with 1 point/ 0 point (or `int` 1/0) for each correct answer, so its a fixed array of `size[4]`.

I am using a for loop, but the durn thing keeps filling the array with 1's if i use `<= score.Length()` method.

I just wish to add an `int` 1 or 0 to score[4] without overwriting the previous element, each time the user answers a question.

```
if( playerTotal < computerTotal || playerTotal > computerTotal) {
    System.out.printf("\n" + "Sorry, thats incorrect...try again__");
    for(int i = 0; i <= score.length ;++i ) {
        score[i] = 0 ;
        System.out.print( " | ");
        System.out.print( score[i]);
    }
} else {
    System.out.print( playerTotal + " is correct, very well done!");
    // in.close();
    for(int i = 0; i <= score.length ;  i++ ) {
        score[i] = 1 ;
        System.out.print( " | ");
        System.out.print( score[i]);
    }
}
```

I hope to use the stored `int`s to move the math game (yayy!) onto the next level after 5 correct points are achieved.

Comment: How does the program get the user input?

Comment: Your `for` loop is overwriting the previous elements. You need to check the implementation logic again.

Comment: The basic math addition ints, are created  using the Random method, which is called twice, and named computerTotal, then using scanner and a  while (!in.hasNext("[0-9]+")) { loop to check the input the answer is passed onto playerTotal and then onto the if then statement...

Comment: Your for loop goes from 0 to        `score.length`  so you write to all elements. why dont you use      `score[4]=1`

Comment: Use a single for loop, inside that get the answer and check whether its correct or not using the if statement.

Comment: Thanks all for the advice, cheers, D

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a for loop if you want to set one element.

remove to for loop and write  
`if( playerTotal < computerTotal || playerTotal > computerTotal ) {
score[4]=0;}
else{score[4]=1;}`

Comment: I do need to run through 5 questions for the user to achieve the 5 points or zeros, so currently in my basic program trial, I've set up a overall for loop, that iterates over the main method 5 times, to ask the math question 5 times...so I think a nested for loop in the if then statement is probably a good approach to updating each element in the array for each answer from the user. D

Answer (score 0):

```
score[4] = ( (playerTotal < computerTotal) || (playerTotal > computerTotal)) ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments a few times, the error in your code is the loop overwriting the other values.
I do not know how you interact with the user, but I've provided an example on how you may solve this task. The do-while will ask for an answer until it is correct.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] questions = {"What is 2-1?", "What is 2+1?", "What is 10-5?"};
int[] correctAnswer = {1,3,5};

//keep track of correct/incorrect answer with a boolean value
boolean[] score = new boolean[correctAnswer.length]; 


for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(questions[i]);
    do {
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        score[i] = input == correctAnswer[i];
        if(score[i])
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong, please try again..");
    } while(!score[i]);
}

//do something with the score data
int sum = 0;
for(boolean b : score)
    if(b) sum++;
System.out.println("You got " + sum + " points!");
```

Comment: I interact through a basic method call displaying a "Please add these two numbers "; then a Random method named levelOneAddition called twice, ie:int firstAdd = sck.levelOneAddition(); 
  int secondAdd = sck.levelOneAddition();  // Random called twice, returns a random number into each variable first & second add.
  
  
  
   int computerTotal = firstAdd + secondAdd; // Computer works out the total & holds in variable computerTotal

Comment: Ok, was this just a comment on my question or do you need help with anything?